# css3: element always rotates around center

Tags: css, rotation, css-transitions

I have this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/pY7Vg/2/). As is shown, the element rotates around its center, but what I'm trying is to let it rotate around its left border (or left axis, or y-axis ?). Is this possible ?

Here is my html

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="item">Rotate</div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
#parent {
    -webkit-perspective: 850px ;
    margin-left: 200px ;
}
.item {    
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d ;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5s linear ;
    background-color: grey ;
    width: 200px ;
    -webkit-tranform-origin: top left 0 ;
}
.item.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) ;
}
```

And with javascript I add the class **rotate** to the div.item so it will start to rotate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo

```
-webkit-tranform-origin: top left 0 ;
```

I changed it to

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top left 0;
```

I think this is how you meant it to work(?) [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pY7Vg/3/)